# SQL, How to get the year that an event occurs for the second time

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

If we have data like this:

```
Element Year
--------------
Elem1   2012
Elem1   2013
Elem1   2015
Elem2   2012
Elem2   2013
Elem3   2012
```

And an element fails when there are 2 occurrences *of an element*, how do I get the fail year for each failing element using T-SQL?

```
Elem1 2013
Elem2 2013
```

**EDIT** Added text in italics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding of the question is that for any given elem, you want to return the row with the second-lowest date.  The example was a bit ambiguous, as in both cases that date was 2013.  If I understand correctly, this should do it:

```
select * from table_name as t where 
    (select count(*) from table_name where element = t.element and year < t.year) = 1
```

IE: select each row for which the number of rows with the same element and a lower year is exactly one.

There's very likely a more efficient way, but that should work.  (Didn't have tsql handy, but tested with your example table in mysql.)

Comment: Another approach would be to select all unique elems first, then loop over them and do something like "select * from table_name where elem=<this_elem> order by year limit 1,1".  IE, select the second record with that elem id, ordered by year.  I'd have to do a bit of reading to figure out how to do that loop in tsql though.  Disadvantage is you have to do a sort for each elem, but the advantage is you avoid running a subquery on every single row, so in most cases I expect it would be faster.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is.

```
SELECT *
FROM test
WHERE year IN(
              SELECT year
              FROM test
              GROUP BY year
              HAVING COUNT(1) = 2 )
```

[Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aba9a/14)

Comment: Doesn't that just find all elements in any year that has exactly 2 elements?

Comment: `when there are 2 occurrences`

Comment: Disregard above, i guess that's what he was looking for.

Comment: I took it to mean he wants to return the rows in which each Elem appears for the second time.  IE: First Elem1 is 2012, Second Elem1 is 2013.  The example certainly could have been less ambiguous.

Comment: I think this looks like it is returning the result because the year 2012 occurs twice. Sorry for the ambiguity. I am looking for the result when the element occurs twice, which Is what Nathan is describing